# Python: How to add an integer to an empty list, without using a method?

Tags: python, list, methods, integer

I need to add an integer on to the end of a list. One constraint for the problem I'm solving is that I can't use any methods, so I can't use .append().

I've tried using

```
list = []
list += someInt
```

but that returns

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you done any research on your own before asking this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about
`lst = lst + [someInt]`.

Comment: edited to not use `list`, as [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) is a function.

Answer (score -1):

One more way for some more flavor :) ...IF you can't just use `append`, but can use some other method (`extend`) in this case

```
def t2():
    lst = [1,2]
    lst.extend([3])
    print lst #prints [1, 2, 3]
```